# Periodic Stream in BLoC Pattern Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing a simple chat application, and I had to check-end API with specific time intervals.

but in my BLOC logic I used **Observable**

So how can I change codes to make this stream periodic?

```
final bloc = ConversationBloc();

class ConversationBloc {
  final repository = Repository();
  final conversationFetcher = PublishSubject<ConversationModel>();
  final conversationFetcherStatus = PublishSubject<MessageModel>();

  Observable<ConversationModel> get userConversation =>
      conversationFetcher.stream;

  dispose() async {
    await conversationFetcher.drain();
    conversationFetcher.close();
    conversationFetcherStatus.close();
  }

  fetchUserConversation(toUsernameController) async {
    ConversationModel conversationModel =
        await repository.fetchUserConversation(toUsernameController);
    conversationFetcher.sink.add(conversationModel);
  }

  saveConversation(Data conversation) async {
    try {
      MessageModel conversationModel =
          await repository.saveConversation(conversation);
      conversationFetcherStatus.sink.add(conversationModel);
    } catch (e) {
      conversationFetcherStatus.sink.addError(e);
    }
  }

   fetchUserConversationList(int toUsernameController) async {
    ConversationModel conversationModel =
        await repository.fetchUserConversationList(toUsernameController);
    conversationFetcher.sink.add(conversationModel);
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont see any [periodic](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/0.22.0/rx/Observable/Observable.periodic.html) constructor in your code

Comment: @pskink that is one billion dollar question, How to implement because I dont know how.